# Gradle build hangs after update to Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just updated to Android Studio 1.3, opened an existing project I was working on, tried to run it. Gradle just gets stuck at the "Resolve dependencies':app_debugCompile'", I tried to wait, I waited for over an hour and nothing happened.

How can I solve it to get my app running?

Comment: Same here daily. `Android Studio > 1.1 totally sucks.`

Comment: There are chance s that gradle is upgrading in background, Assuming that having slow internet connection this process might take several minutes( several hours) to complete. If not that Try reinstalling Android Studio.

Comment: I tried to create a new project and it compiled successfully,  I think it is some backwards compatibility issue

Answer (score 5):

If you are using proxy, it seems https proxy server setting is not correctly done in Android studio 1.3.
You can set https proxy server manually in gradle.properties,

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.server.address
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

see [Gradle Sync fails in Android studio 1.3](http://corochann.com/gradle-sync-fails-in-android-studio-1-3-300.html) and [gradle behind proxy in Android Studio 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803610/gradle-behind-proxy-in-android-studio-1-3).

Comment: ah! I was using http instead of https and that was the reason of stuck!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve it to get my app running?

Start by identifying the problem more precisely. To do so, run gradle from the command line in the root directory of your project :

```
./gradlew --debug clean build
```

The `--debug` argument will simply enable the debug log level and hopefully providing useful information to understand where/why it is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem in linux and my problem solved after installing these dependencies on fedora :

```
sudo dnf install glibc.i686 zlib.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.Just see this page. [Solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36529301/5037958)

**Solution :**

1. Make sure you have latest stable version ( current 2.0.0 )
2. Make sure your gradle version is 2.0.0 in build.gradle ( classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0')
3. Final step and most important one is change your **jcenter()** to **mavenCentral()**

So you can easily add new dependency and sync project under 3sec !

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to app > Right Click on it > Open Module Settings>Change build tool version to 22.0.1 
Try again after restarting your Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue in the OP, in my case it was taking over 20min just to get gradle build going. Getting stuck at the **"Resolve dependencies':app_debugCompile'"** as well.

I'm still relatively new to Stackoverflow so I can't up-vote yet. But what I can tell you is that if your behind a web proxy like I am and you've just updated to Android 1.3.1 you will probably notice this issue immediately.  I already had my companies web proxy in the IDE settngs and yes there is something not ok with the **1.3.1** update. As **corochann** posted you have to add the proxy info to the **gradle.properties** of your project. Once I actually did this I noticed the difference immediately.  Going forward until its resolved you'll probably have to add this to each project if your behind a web proxy and running 1.3.1.  I have another machine at home that isn't behind a proxy and is running Android Studio version before 1.3.0 and had no issues.  Hope this helps!!